# Changing org.gradle.jvmargs Value

Tags: java, android, gradle, jvm-arguments, gradle.properties

before a while, I was able to work on android studio project with the gradle property set to
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`.
suddenly now, for a reason I don't realize I Can't sync gradle files unless I set it to `Xmx-1024m`
so I cleaned all android files and uninstalled the jdk and android studio and gradle files then reinstalled all, the problem still exists.

what's the problem exactly? and what's happening when doing this change

Comment: Can you explain in detail the problem you received?